# exec with empty string or space

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I just want to know whats happening behind this. If i execute the following SQL statement.

```
exec('')
```

It says,

> Command(s) completed successfully.

Same for the `exec('           ')`

Also, when you execute a space in SMSS directly

As of my knowledge, `exec` expects a SQL Statement or a stored procedure to run. But here if i passed the **Empty string** or **one or more than one character space**, How it has been handled?

Comment: I would guess the same as when you execute a space in SMSS directly, this also displays 'Command(s) completed successfully.'

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes, Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing of the command happens :
Nothing to be executed.

End of the command : success.